# How to make string non nullable?

Tags: c#

I am trying to do my college project and in that title and author should be string type and not null but as much as I knew string is a reference type and it can be null.
The other options that I know is to check manually like String.isNullOrEmpty(stringName) but I would like to know other options that I can have.

If marked nullable, the property is optional and can be null. Otherwise, a value should always be present.

- Id (read-only)
- Title
- Author
- Page count
- Times borrowed
- Borrower (nullable)
- Borrow date (nullable)
- Due date (nullable)

Comment: Strings are allowed to be null, so the only thing you can do is throw if the string IsNullOrEmpty.

Comment: Enable nullable reference types. That way you can get warnings

Comment: Does using a `[NotNull]` attribute help here?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a constructor and use getter-only properties for the members you do not want to be nullable.

For example, consider a `Person` class with `FirstName` and `LastName` as required members and `MiddleName` as optional.

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstName))
            throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or whitespace.", nameof(firstName));

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lastName))
            throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or whitespace.", nameof(lastName));

        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public string FirstName { get; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make constructors that forbid nulls. And the same for properties